# Unexpected keyword 'auth_token' using python gdata GetContacts()

Tags: python, gdata, google-contacts-api

Why do I get the keyword error shown below when running the following code? It is failing on the last line: `feed = gc.GetContacts()`.

**Code**

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
import gdata.contacts.client

authfn = '/home/ms/gcontactsback.oauth'
f = open(authfn, "r")
credentials = OAuth2Credentials.from_json(f.read())
f.close()

gc = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='gback')
gc = credentials.authorize(gc)
feed = gc.GetContacts()
```

**Output**

```
(py)ms@ny:~/py$ ./gcontacts.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gcontacts.py", line 19, in <module>
    feed = gc.GetContacts()
  File "/home/ms/py/local/lib/python2.7/site-
      packages/gdata/contacts/client.py", line 201, in get_contacts
  desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ms/py/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/client.py",
   line 640, in get_feed
   **kwargs)
  File "/home/ms/py/local/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
  return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: new_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_token'

(py)ms@ny:~/py$
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way:

```
gc = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='gback')
auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
gc = auth2token.authorize(gc)
feed = gc.GetContacts()
```